# Where to input my favorite tags?

Tags: support, tags

This is really strange to me. I can't find any part of SO to enter my favorite tags. I know I've used it before but I can't find the part of SO page any more. I searched about it on meta site without success so it may be just me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either in your profile, in the "Prefs" tab (link at the top of your user page), or in the right sidebar on the various Question pages.

[Your preferences on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/749973)

Comment: Got it! I remember that UI part was floating somewhere on questions page and that started my confusion. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Image:

[image: favourite tags]

It's on the right side of the page.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know if I remove all favorite tags then the ui part on right side disappears. Thanks anyway.